# No messages displayed by consumer on running producer and consumer python scripts

Tags: apache-kafka, ubuntu-16.04, kafka-python

I set up Apache Kafka on an Ubuntu server and tested it by following through first five steps mentioned in https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart and things worked fine.

I then proceeded with the installation of kafka-python 1.4.6 to test in python and wrote simple producer and consumer scripts.

My configuration for listeners
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

Here are the scripts

consum.py

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic')
for message in consumer:
        print (message)
```

prod.py

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',api_version=(0, 10, 1))

producer.send('my-topic', b'Hello')
```

On running the scripts the producer script completes immediately and no message is printed by consumer script

Any ideas what I might be missing here.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your producer script finishes before the message is sent. After running `send()`, Python reaches the last line of your script and stops running immediately.

You need to call [`flush()`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaProducer.html#kafka.KafkaProducer.flush) to force the runtime to wait for all messages to be sent before terminating.

```python
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',api_version=(0, 10, 1))

producer.send('my-topic', b'Hello')

producer.flush()
```

Apart from that your logic looks fine (and worked for me).

Comment: by adding producer.flush() to producer script, the consumer was able to print the message